# Setting font size in application

Tags: android, photoshop

I am developing an android application. My designer gave me designs with font size 48PT in photoshop. For android how many DPs should I set in font size?

Comment: you should use SP for font size - not DP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert pt to sp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404377/how-do-i-convert-pt-to-sp)

Comment: i think you have to set apperence of text to largfe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

This site helps you to convert your values px,dp,sp,pt,etc..
make sure you are using the right Density  in the drop down.

Your 48dp equals 107sp and 106dp

Answer (score 0):

Create dimen.xml for your solution.

Directory will be as follow

**1. res -> values-ldpi --> dimen.xml**

**2. res -> values-mdpi --> dimen.xml**

**3. res -> values-hdpi --> dimen.xml**

**4. res -> values-xhdpi --> dimen.xml**

**5. res -> values-xxhdpi --> dimen.xml**

in that file create

```
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">size in sp</dimen>
</resources>`
```

Size will be different for all devices set that according to your layout and requirements.

Now Give Your Textview size with

`android:textsize="@dimen/text_size"`

Comment: `dp`, `sp`, and `pt` are all density-independent and do not normally need separate definitions per density.

Comment: If i want to give support to all devices like(320X480 ,480X800 , 800x1280 ,1080X1920). and if i give same font size to textview for ex. 100pt. Then text font's size will varies with devices. Then what to do?

Comment: "Then text font's size will varies with devices" -- it shouldn't. A point (pt) is 1/72 of an inch, and that does not depend on density.